# RQT not showing icons in OSX

Tags: rqt, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I just upgraded to the latest releases of rqt as announced on the mailing list earlier today, hoping this would help.
rqt does not show icons for the plugins, e.g. the "refresh" or "help" icon under osx 10.8. It looks worst for rqt_bag, which is somewhat unusable in this state, as shown in the screenshot. Any ideas what that could be?[image: screenshot]

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60017/rqt-not-showing-icons-in-osx/) by [Markus Achtelik](https://answers.ros.org/users/867/markus-achtelik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 390 on 2013-04-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rqt` uses the `tango-icon-theme` for the icons. This package is available on ubuntu, but is not available through Homebrew (yet).

For now the dependency is left unresolved:

https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml#L381

`rqt` (specifically `rqt_bag` in this case) might better handle this by falling back to system icons, but this may not be possible.

As a work around you can download, build and install the tango-icon-theme from source:

http://tango.freedesktop.org/releases/tango-icon-theme-0.8.90.tar.gz

By following the instructions here:

http://tango.freedesktop.org/Installation#Tango_Icon_Theme

This should allow `rqt` to show the icons, but I have never tried it myself.

**EDIT:**

I have created the required `tango-icon-theme` and `icon-naming-utils` formulae:

https://github.com/ros/homebrew-groovy/blob/master/icon-naming-utils.rb
https://github.com/ros/homebrew-groovy/blob/master/tango-icon-theme.rb

If you already have the `ros/groovy` tap, then just do `brew update`, otherwise do `brew tap ros/groovy`.

I updated the rosdep entry, so now the `tango-icon-theme` should get installed automatically when following the source installation instructions:

https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/commit/9b35f250af19b253f278bfdb45af32fe961a32d1

Then I had to patch `qt_gui_core` to include `/usr/local/share/icons` to the icon search path for `rqt`:

https://github.com/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/pull/17

So if you install `tango-icon-theme` and apply that patch to `qt_gui_core` then you get something like this:

[image: rqt_bag]

So there seems to be some other problem related to button positioning in `rqt_bag`.

I have opened an issue:

https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues/68

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Achtelik](https://answers.ros.org/users/867/markus-achtelik/) on 2013-04-04**:
This is awesome, thanks a lot !! Will try it tomorrow morning, it's fairly late here already

**Comment by [Markus Achtelik](https://answers.ros.org/users/867/markus-achtelik/) on 2013-04-05**:
The steps above helped, thanks a lot again! For rqt_bag, I get the same behaviour as shown above by William, which is already a lot nicer than before.